# Can't turn audit logging off in Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

We're getting spammed in our `artemis.log` with log messages from `org.apache.activemq.audit.message` and `org.apache.activemq.audit.base`, like the following:

```
2020-06-04 12:02:26,151 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.audit.message] AMQ601500: User xxx is sending a core message on target resource: ...
```

and

```
2020-06-04 12:02:26,081 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.audit.base] AMQ601019: User amq|xxx| is getting mbean info on target resource: org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.management.impl.AddressControlImpl@60975100 []
```

We've added the following lines to our `logging.properties` with no luck:

```
logger.org.apache.activemq.audit.base.level=ERROR
logger.org.apache.activemq.audit.message.level=ERROR
```

What's going on here?  How do we turn these off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you haven't configured your `logging.properties` appropriately to ignore messages from those loggers. You've added lines to set the `level` for those loggers, but have you added those loggers to the `loggers` list?

For example, this is the default `logging.properties` shipped with ActiveMQ Artemis 2.13.0:

```
loggers=org.eclipse.jetty,org.jboss.logging,org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server,org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils,org.apache.activemq.artemis.journal,org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.server,org.apache.activemq.artemis.integration.bootstrap,org.apache.activemq.audit.base,org.apache.activemq.audit.message,org.apache.activemq.audit.resource

# Root logger level
logger.level=INFO
# ActiveMQ Artemis logger levels
logger.org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.level=INFO
logger.org.apache.activemq.artemis.journal.level=INFO
logger.org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.level=INFO
logger.org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.level=INFO
logger.org.apache.activemq.artemis.integration.bootstrap.level=INFO
logger.org.eclipse.jetty.level=WARN
# Root logger handlers
logger.handlers=FILE,CONSOLE

# to enable audit change the level to INFO
logger.org.apache.activemq.audit.base.level=ERROR
logger.org.apache.activemq.audit.base.handlers=AUDIT_FILE
logger.org.apache.activemq.audit.base.useParentHandlers=false

logger.org.apache.activemq.audit.resource.level=ERROR
logger.org.apache.activemq.audit.resource.handlers=AUDIT_FILE
logger.org.apache.activemq.audit.resource.useParentHandlers=false

logger.org.apache.activemq.audit.message.level=ERROR
logger.org.apache.activemq.audit.message.handlers=AUDIT_FILE
logger.org.apache.activemq.audit.message.useParentHandlers=false

# Console handler configuration
handler.CONSOLE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.ConsoleHandler
handler.CONSOLE.properties=autoFlush
handler.CONSOLE.level=DEBUG
handler.CONSOLE.autoFlush=true
handler.CONSOLE.formatter=PATTERN

# File handler configuration
handler.FILE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler
handler.FILE.level=DEBUG
handler.FILE.properties=suffix,append,autoFlush,fileName
handler.FILE.suffix=.yyyy-MM-dd
handler.FILE.append=true
handler.FILE.autoFlush=true
handler.FILE.fileName=${artemis.instance}/log/artemis.log
handler.FILE.formatter=PATTERN

# Formatter pattern configuration
formatter.PATTERN=org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.PatternFormatter
formatter.PATTERN.properties=pattern
formatter.PATTERN.pattern=%d %-5p [%c] %s%E%n

#Audit logger
handler.AUDIT_FILE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler
handler.AUDIT_FILE.level=INFO
handler.AUDIT_FILE.properties=suffix,append,autoFlush,fileName
handler.AUDIT_FILE.suffix=.yyyy-MM-dd
handler.AUDIT_FILE.append=true
handler.AUDIT_FILE.autoFlush=true
handler.AUDIT_FILE.fileName=${artemis.instance}/log/audit.log
handler.AUDIT_FILE.formatter=AUDIT_PATTERN

formatter.AUDIT_PATTERN=org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.PatternFormatter
formatter.AUDIT_PATTERN.properties=pattern
formatter.AUDIT_PATTERN.pattern=%d [AUDIT](%t) %s%E%n
```

Notice that the first line defines the `loggers` list and includes `org.apache.activemq.audit.base`, `org.apache.activemq.audit.message`, & `org.apache.activemq.audit.resource`.

Comment: I was missing the loggers in that first line, you're right.  Thank you - you're a lifesaver.